# What is the Order argument in custom FilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

With the code below, when I use the attribute in the controller, I see my 3 arguments and one more "Order" what is this ? How remove it ? It's not last in my parameters position but in the middle (strange)

```
public class TestingFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public TestingFilterAttribute()
    {
    }

    public string FieldA { get; set; }
    public int FieldB { get; set; }
    public int FieldC { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        .....
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

**Update :**

I'd like in this attribute, do a security check in database and redirect to another page in some conditions.

Comment: If you derive from the `ActionFilterAttribute` which derives form `FilterAttribute` you will have an `Order` property which is defined in the `FilterAttribute` class. If you don't need it just ignore it you don't need to specify it when you are using your `TestingFilterAttribute` attribute.

Comment: Attribute properties matched by name so you can left out `Order` . So `[TestingFilter(FieldA = "a", FieldC = 1, FieldB = 2)]` is a valid usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order is inherited from ActionFilterAttribute. Some ActionFilters can do things such as returning an action early or redirecting elsewhere which prevents subsequent filters from executing, when you have multiple actionfilters you can supply an order so that they are executed in the order that you want.

Comment: Ok. But I don't need it. What can I do ? it's not possible to ignore it.

Comment: @Kris-I It's an inherited named parameter, you can't get rid of it. You can ignore it, provide a value or even have a constructor with parameters for your properties, at least then there will be an intellisense option that doesn't include it.